# typescript webpack transpile to UMD, having to call class.class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am trying to get a test I made to understand how `webpack` compiles typescript so I can convert my code over from javascript.

When I transpile my typescript to javascript using `webpack` and `awesome-typescript-loader` my TEST class gets exported but in order to call the constructor I need to call TEST.TEST, as you can see in my html test file. But this is not what I expect. I expect to be able to call the constructor directly via `var T = new TEST(); not var T = new TEST.TEST();`.

I have the following files/code:

**src/test.ts**

```
export class TEST {
    thing: string;

    constructor(thing: string) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    print_thing() {
        console.log(this.thing);
    }
}
```

**src/test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script>var t = new TEST.TEST("thing"); t.print_thing();</script>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declarationDir": "dist/typings",
        "outDir": "dist/lib",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

var resolve = require('path').resolve;

```
module.exports = {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/test.ts'),
    output: {
        filename: 'test.js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'TEST',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.ts',
            '.tsx',
            '.js'
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var gulpwebpack = require("webpack-stream");
var del = require('del');

gulp.task("copy-html", function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task("default", ["copy-html"], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulpwebpack(require("./webpack.config"), webpack))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task("clean", function() {
    del(['dist']);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your class is exposed under `TEST.TEST` instead of just `TEST` is because of the `library` option in your Webpack config.

By setting `library` to a non-empty string, you're telling Webpack to encapsulate all of your code under the name `TEST`. So, if you had another class in your `test.ts` - call it `BLAH` - it would be exposed under `TEST.BLAH`.

If you want to make all of your top-level exported members available globally, simply remove the `library` option in your Webpack config.